# Low contrast text --- doesn't meet WCAG standards

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, accessibility

WCAG standards for accessible text are massively ignored on SE:

Placeholder text for the Textarea element:

> [image]
>   [image]

Inactive tabs:

> [image]
>   [image]

"Joined ..." notes:

> [image]
>   [image]

All these elements are poorly visible due to low contrast.
As per the [WCAG 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#contrast-minimum) Success Criterion 1.4.3 - for minimum contrast

> visual presentation of text and images of text has a contrast ratio of at least 4.5:1

Comment: As I posted in a comment to your other question, rather than hoping, users with accessibility issues mostly need to work out their own solutions. By the way, I feel both your questions are accessibility issues which should be viewed more sympathetically!

Comment: Tell that to the designers of [Windows Aero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero) and of [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)) (all hinders effective use - you have learn the number of TABs by heart to avoid using the [harmful rodent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_mouse)).

Comment: hypothetically - I suspect those things are low contrast to make them less obvious. What would be a way to do that *while* maintaining good contrast?

Comment: @DKBose - While to a certain extent, yes, there are ways for people to improve their own experiences and adjust things to suit their needs, that doesn't mean that we shouldn't be trying to stick to accessibility guidelines. It can only help.

Comment: @Mithical I absolutely agree with you but I fear it isn't a priority, not just here but on many non-SE sites. There are [complaints about grey on grey](https://forum.webflow.com/t/help-stamp-out-grey-text/38028/2) but it's still common.

Comment: I [found this](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html): *Incidental: Text or images of text that are part of an inactive user interface component, that are pure decoration, that are not visible to anyone, or that are part of a picture that contains significant other visual content, have no contrast requirement.*